# Cookie information sharing and management mechanism

Tags: gui-design, popup, cookies

I went on the [Red Dot Design](https://www.red-dot.org/) website and was greeted by this interesting pop-up:

[image]

I really like how it has clarified the Cookie information, but it actually doesn't seem to allow any selection other than to Allow all cookies.

Are there other examples out there that have better user experiences and more flexibility in what you can accept or decline?

Comment: There definitely are! It depends on how well the website has been built, which is a telltale sign as to how well the web/digital aspect of the business is managed...many simply outsource the problem of GDPR and end up with mediocre controls for it. I can't find examples because I am in Australia, a country that you shouldn't trust with private data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nice way. Unfortunately it is in Romanian but it explains what the cookies do and let's you deactivate the one that you don't like.

[image]